# GRUB MAKING A NEW ENTRY FOR Android x86

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, android

I have installed Android x86. It is on my HDD now. Location /dev/sda8, contents: ext4 v-1.

Now in installation it told to download grub. I first pressed skip. Then rebooted but no option to boot in to Android x86. I again booted through live cd and installed grub. Again no changes made. I want to add a new entry in grub menu so that I can boot in to Android x86 also. I have the grub file of Android x86 because I chose to download that also.

Android Source: https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/releases
android-x86-8.1-r6.iso

Ubuntu 20.04, Windows 10 and Android x86 currently installed.(I want to boot in to Ubuntu. If I can't boot into windows that would not matter but I am not in a mood of downloading a tons of GB's of crap.)

Comment: Have you tried booing your Ubuntu and entering `sudo update-grub` ?   I've not used android x86, but I'd expect that to detect a *ext4* partition with another GNU/Linux system on it.

Comment: What does your grub look like? Can you update your question and add the text please? You can use the command `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` to open it in up.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm...
I had also windows with my linux so i did solving this problem by just simply installing EasyBCD on my windows
created a new entry named ANDROID-X86 (neogrub) and then
booted to linux
copied all the files from {partition where android-x86 is installed}/grub  to  {partition where windows is installed}/NST/
opened menu.lst and entered my hardisk and partition no. there ie. hd(1,5)[yours can be different]....and..saved it.
it appeared on my windows bootloader
it is preety complex and **needs windows installed** butt... it works :)

**edited**
now i even managed to do what u want to
[this](https://softwareguidehelp.wordpress.com/2020/04/17/how-to-install-android-x86-from-ubuntu-dual-boot/) may help

Comment: This is very very confusing. Do not know if this is an answer to the question as asked by the OP but I do not think so.